# Aria-label not showing on image

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js

Trying to get the aria-label to show on my image, but it is not working. Cannot figure out what is missing, why it does not work?

Here code (NextJS app):

In my public folder the svg.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="122.875px" height="28.489px" viewBox="0 0 122.875 28.489" enable-background="new 0 0 122.875 28.489" xml:space="preserve"><g><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M108.993,0c7.683-0.059,13.898,6.12,13.882,13.805 c-0.018,7.682-6.26,13.958-13.942,14.018c-31.683,0.222-63.368,0.444-95.051,0.666C6.2,28.549-0.016,22.369,0,14.685 C0.018,7.002,6.261,0.726,13.943,0.667C45.626,0.445,77.311,0.223,108.993,0L108.993,0z"/></g></svg>
```

Then in my data folder, I import the svg.

```
import Minus from "public/minus-icon.svg";

export list = [
  { name: "One two and three and four and five till six and stop", icon: Minus }
]
```

Then in my component:

```
<Image
                  priority
                  src={item.icon}
                  height={20}
                  width={20}
                  alt={item.name}
                  aria-labelledby={item.name}
                />
                <title id={item.name}>{item.name}</title>
```

It all works nicely like this (not relevant code for this post is left out such as `import Image from "next/image";` ), but why NO aria-label is shown in front-end upon hover, no idea. Anyone? Thanks for helping. P.S. If I just use the svg directly, inline code I mean, then with the above aria-label code all works and I can see front-end the label upon hover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aria` tags should not have an effect on the front end. They are used for accessibility purposes, (Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA). If you want text to show up when the mouse hovers over an image you can use the `title` attribute on an image.

Try:

```
<Image
    priority
    src={item.icon}
    height={20}
    width={20}
    alt={item.name}
    title={item.name}
 />
```